# C Problem passing pointer to struct in an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I am translating a program from Pascal to C. It has been many years since I used the C language. Here is a relevant code snippet:

```
typedef struct querec *queptr;
struct querec {
    char item;
    queptr next;
};
struct queue {
    queptr front,
    rear;
};
struct queue qnum[5];
char item;

const char remove(struct queue *q)
{
    queptr p;
    char remove_result;

    p = q->front;
    remove_result = p->item;
    q->front = p->next;
    if (q->front == NULL)
        q->rear = NULL;
    return remove_result;
}

main()
{
    ...
    item = remove(&qnum[3]);
}
```

It will not compile in Visual Studio 2015, reporting the following:

```
Warning C4133   'function': incompatible types - from 'queue *' to 'const char *'
Error   C2373   'remove': redefinition; different type modifiers
```

Comment: `main()` has been obsolete for quite some time.  The proper prototype is `int main(void)`.  You should also remove the `const` qualifier on the return type of the `remove` function, which of course should be renamed to prevent a conflict with the standard function `remove` defined in `<stdio.h>` that deletes a file from the file system (using the `unlink` system call on POSIX systems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `remove` should be renamed to prevent a conflict with the standard function `remove` declared as `int remove(const char *filename);` in `<stdio.h>` that deletes a file from the file system (using the `unlink` system call on POSIX systems).
- `main()` has been obsolete for quite some time.  The proper prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`.
- You should also remove the `const` qualifier on the return type of the `remove` function.
- hiding pointers behind typedefs is confusing and error prone, especially when the type name is unrelated to the pointed to type.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct queue_record queue_record;
typedef struct queue queue;

struct queue_record {
    char item;
    queue_record *next;
};

struct queue {
    queue_record *front;
    queue_record *rear;
};

char queue_remove(queue *q)
{
    queue_record *p;
    char remove_result = 0;

    p = q->front;
    if (p) {
        remove_result = p->item;
        q->front = p->next;
        if (q->front == NULL)
            q->rear = NULL;
        // XXX: should probably free(p)?
    }
    return remove_result;
}

int main(void)
{
    queue qnum[5];
    char item;

    //...
    item = queue_remove(&qnum[3]);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "redefinition" just wasn't enough clue for my feeble brain. remove() was probably added to stdio.h since the last time I used C (except in embedded systems.) Your modified version, using free(p) brings up an interesting question (and memory.) The original Pascal did have a DIspose(p) statement in the same place as you suggest. However, in C, I believe it will be placed on the stack and disposed on function return.  However, Pascal (at least my recollection of it on a VAX in the 80's) required it because Pascal was very elegant in allowing assignment of entire structures (among other ways.).

Answer (score 5):

The C language does not have function overloading, and it happens that [`int remove(const char*)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove) is a standard C library function.

To fix the error, you need to call your function something else, such as `queue_remove` for example.

Note that when the compiler gives errors like this, it will usually output additional information showing you the conflicting definitions. In this case, it should have shown you that `remove` was declared in `stdio.h` or a related internal file. Even though it can feel like information overload, it's always worth taking time to read the message carefully.

Comment: Paddy, your answer is correct and you were first to answer, but I chose Chqrlie's answer because he also provided a solution (and pointed out extraneous other issues I was aware of.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be careful about using the name `remove`.

It is a standard function, defined in `stdio.h`.

See: `man 3 remove` It has a prototype of:

```
int remove(const char *pathname);
```